# Postman API won't skip empty rows of CSV

Tags: api, csv, testing, automation, postman

I'm trying to run a collection of API tests in Postman and use the IDs from a CSV file as a variable in the URL to check each possible endpoint.

My problem is there are more of `sID`s than `InteractionID`s, so when it runs out of interaction id's it just keeps running the test but leaving it blank meaning the tests all fail.

I just wondered if there is a way to tell Postman to stop running the interaction part of the runner or something I can put in the CSV file to skip the empty rows.

My current workaround is to have the data in separate CSV files and run the tests separately.

[image: Sample of the CSV Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a workflow rule in the Tests and add some logic to check if the `InteractionID` variable is empty. If it is, it will end the execution with `postman.setNextRequest(null)` - https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/building_workflows